# Kill or close websocket on apollo-server after jest test

Tags: jestjs, apollo, apollo-server

I would like to know how can I close the websocket after the jest test ?

Currently I have this :

> packages.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "globalSetup": "./tests/jest/globalSetup.js",
    "globalTeardown": "./tests/jest/globalTeardown.js"
  },
```

> server.js

```
...
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context(request) {
        return {
            prisma,
            request,
        }
    },
})

export { server as default }
```

> globalSetup.js

```
require("@babel/register")

const server = require("../../server").default

// console.log(server)
module.exports = async () => {
    global.httpServer = await server.listen({ port: 4000 })
}
```

> globalTeardown.js

```
module.exports = async () => {
    console.log("stop") // Show stop in the console
    await global.httpServer.stop
}
```

I launch this command :

**npm run test**

The test are executed, but on the watch, if I modify one test, I have this error :

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1449:7)
    at /Users/jeremiechazelle/Sites/project/server/node_modules/apollo-server/src/index.ts:128:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at ApolloServer.<anonymous> (/Users/jeremiechazelle/Sites/project/server/node_modules/apollo-server/src/index.ts:123:11)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/jeremiechazelle/Sites/project/server/node_modules/apollo-server/dist/index.js:18:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/jeremiechazelle/Sites/project/server/node_modules/apollo-server/dist/index.js:14:12)
Emitted 'error' event on WebSocketServer instance at:
    at Server.emit (events.js:316:20)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1340:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -48,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 4000
}
```

After the test are executed, I look the port 4000, with this command : **lsof -i:4000**, and I see always :

[image]

The port isn't close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server.listen` returns a Promise that resolves to a `ServerInfo` object

```
export interface ServerInfo {
  address: string;
  family: string;
  url: string;
  subscriptionsUrl: string;
  port: number | string;
  subscriptionsPath: string;
  server: http.Server;
}
```

So you need to call `global.httpServer.server.close()`.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel for your answer, but when I write await global.httpServer.stop(), I see an error : TypeError: global.httpServer.stop is not a function.
From this issue : https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/3964

Comment: You'd need to show the module you're importing with `require("../../server").default`. If what you're exporting is an express instance, for example, it doesn't have a `stop` method but has a `close` method.

Comment: I updated my post, I import an ApolloServer instance. I tried with close(), but I have a same issue : TypeError: global.httpServer.close is not a function

Comment: Thank you @Daniel !